# Prestashop: Natural Sort for sort by 'Product Name: A to Z'

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, natural-sort

Using **blockLayered**, when sorting by 'Product Name: A to Z', I get the following results:

- "someCode 10W - some string"
- "someCode 16W - some string"
- "someCode 25W - some string"
- "someCode 34W - some string"
- "someCode 5W - some string"
- "someCode 7W - some string"

Though I want them to be ordered by "natural Order" as

- "someCode 5W - some string"
- "someCode 7W - some string"
- "someCode 10W - some string"
- "someCode 16W - some string"
- "someCode 25W - some string"
- "someCode 34W - some string"

In blockLayered code, I can see a call to natcasesort() http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php

similiar to "layered filters involving features are now natural sorted" - https://gitlab.com/alfons83/PrestaShop/commit/f0abdca08f367b99b8c970f77f13dd4626fd32ee - I do have such code in my source, but in other line-numbers.

but I am not sure it is used with sort by 'Product Name: A to Z'.
is 'name' considered 'id_feature' ?

- If it is used, why "5w" and "7w" are last?
- If it is not used, how\where should I use it?

Comment: I am not sure it relates to blockLayered . . .

Comment: It is sorted by MySQL query. It can't recognize "5W" is less than "10W", it sorts character by character, so "someCode 1..." is less than "someCode 5...".

Comment: can I use natcasesort() to re-order the query results? if yes, where and how?

Comment: Go to `modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.php` and modify `getProductByFilters()`.

Comment: what should be the modification?

Comment: Grab the MySQL results there and rearrange with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

go to Preferences -> products

look in the "paging" call. You can find them "default order." Li select "product name"